# variable background colors in google line chart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I'm looking to draw a fairly simple google LineChart, but I'd like to have horizontal coloured bands across the chart area, to indicate low/middle/high values.

Looking at the chart API, it does not appear to be possibly directly, as `chartArea.backgroundColor` appears to be the only value I can set.

Being aware that this appears to be a limitation of the charts, is it possible to recreate this any other way, through any other methods or javascript wizardry?

Below is an example of what sort of effect I'm looking to produce.
[image: Example of desired effect]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you could use a combo chart, with a stacked area series to apply the shading...

Comment: Thanks for the comment, though I'm not quite sure that would work. Perhaps for vertical coloured regions, but not for what I'm after. Perhaps I'm mistaken, could you mock something up in jsfiddle to demonstrate how you mean?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

using a [ComboChart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/combochart)

with `seriesType: 'area'`

and `isStacked: true`

you can define as many ranges as needed

`visibleInLegend: false` hides the area series from the legend

then you can set a custom `type:` for the series you want to track,
such as `'line'`, in the following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable({
      cols: [
        {label: 'Time', type: 'number'},
        {label: 'Low', type: 'number'},
        {label: 'Avg', type: 'number'},
        {label: 'High', type: 'number'},
        {label: 'Dogs', type: 'number'}
      ],
      rows: [
        {c:[{v: 0}, {v: 25}, {v: 50}, {v: 25}, {v: 0}]},
        {c:[{v: 5}, {v: 25}, {v: 50}, {v: 25}, {v: 24}]},
        {c:[{v: 10}, {v: 25}, {v: 50}, {v: 25}, {v: 20}]},
        {c:[{v: 15}, {v: 25}, {v: 50}, {v: 25}, {v: 48}]},
        {c:[{v: 20}, {v: 25}, {v: 50}, {v: 25}, {v: 53}]},
        {c:[{v: 25}, {v: 25}, {v: 50}, {v: 25}, {v: 61}]},
        {c:[{v: 30}, {v: 25}, {v: 50}, {v: 25}, {v: 63}]},
        {c:[{v: 40}, {v: 25}, {v: 50}, {v: 25}, {v: 66}]},
        {c:[{v: 45}, {v: 25}, {v: 50}, {v: 25}, {v: 70}]},
        {c:[{v: 50}, {v: 25}, {v: 50}, {v: 25}, {v: 75}]},
        {c:[{v: 55}, {v: 25}, {v: 50}, {v: 25}, {v: 78}]},
        {c:[{v: 60}, {v: 25}, {v: 50}, {v: 25}, {v: 80}]},
        {c:[{v: 65}, {v: 25}, {v: 50}, {v: 25}, {v: 85}]},
        {c:[{v: 70}, {v: 25}, {v: 50}, {v: 25}, {v: 90}]}
      ]
    });

    var options = {
      chartArea: {
        width: '60%'
      },
      hAxis: {
        ticks: [0, 15, 30, 45, 60],
        title: 'Time'
      },
      isStacked: true,
      series: {
        // low
        0: {
          areaOpacity: 0.6,
          color: '#FFF59D',
          visibleInLegend: false
        },

        // avg
        1: {
          areaOpacity: 0.6,
          color: '#A5D6A7',
          visibleInLegend: false
        },

        // high
        2: {
          areaOpacity: 0.6,
          color: '#EF9A9A',
          visibleInLegend: false
        },

        // dogs
        3: {
          color: '#01579B',
          type: 'line'
        }
      },
      seriesType: 'area',
      title: 'Example',
      vAxis: {
        ticks: [0, 25, 50, 75, 100],
        title: 'Popularity'
      }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(dataTable, options);
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```