# Creating Google Line Charts with horizontal bands

Tags: google-visualization

I am working with [Google Line Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart) to show data coming from remote embedded devices. It works well for my application and has proven to be the right choice due its speed on loading multiple charts at the same time.

However, these devices are run on battery. If not recharged often, the batteries drop their voltage levels fast. If they stay low for too long, the device is required to hibernate in order to not corrupt data, and consequently stop sending it to the application server.

Thus I would like to show horizontal bands on the chart's background, creating colored zones. The visual effect would make it easier to the user to identify the issue. What I want to accomplish is the same seen in this image:

[image: chart with colored background areas]

Although my levels would be:

- Ideal: > 4.0 V
- OK: 3.7 V - 4.0 V
- Poor: < 3.7 V

Is there any way to do it with Google Charts? Does anyone have any alternative suggestions?

Comment: check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39671447/5090771)...

Comment: @WhiteHat that was exactly it I was look for! Thank you so much.