# Google charts with datepicker

Tags: javascript, charts, datepicker, google-visualization

Im currently creating a dashboard, I'm getting my data via
google analytics api which I already have stored in tables.

I now want to visualize that data in a google charts LINE chart.
I uderstand how to display the data in the line chart.

My question is: I have a custom datepicker. How do I fill in the h-axis
according to the currently selected date range in the datepicker, and have it change the date values?

I want it to be like so: [embed api line chart](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/custom-components/)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: although an unrelated question, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42510168/5090771) shows how to use `hAxis.ticks` to set the date range and labels shown on h-axis -- see [linechart configuration options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#configuration-options) for details...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found the answer. Just put date as a dimension when querying 
and put it in the first column of each row to get it on the x-axis.
Mind to parse the json format date, because dataTable will not
recognize it as a valid date type.