# Drawing a stacked series of bars with width dimension and a smoothed trend line

Tags: javascript, charts

I got a number of small datasets which I'd like to visualise on charts. These goal is to represent a learning curve based on calendar time, number of hours spent studying and perceived complexity.

The datasets look like this:

```
| Day No | Date       | Hours | Complexity |
| ------ | ---------- | ----- |----------- |
|      1 | 2017-03-07 |     4 |          8 |
|      2 | 2017-03-08 |     6 |          3 |
|      3 | 2017-03-09 |     3 |         10 |
|      4 | 2017-03-13 |     7 |          2 |
|      5 | 2017-03-16 |     4 |          5 |
|      6 | 2017-03-17 |     9 |          8 |
|      7 | 2017-03-20 |     4 |          3 |
|      8 | 2017-03-22 |     4 |          3 |
|      9 | 2017-03-24 |     6 |          6 |
|     10 | 2017-03-25 |     6 |          7 |
|     11 | 2017-03-27 |     7 |          8 |
|     12 | 2017-03-28 |     8 |          8 |
```

Where

```
Day No - uninterrupted sequence of days
Date - calendar date some studying took place, can have gaps
Hours - hours spent studying during the day
Complexity - perceived complexity of the material on scale of 1 to 10
```

In terms of visualization I'm thinking of something like this (sorry for the irregularity):
[image: Learning curve chart prototype]

Where each block's height represents `Hours` and width represents `Complexity`. Horizontal axis has fixed width steps representing whole Days. Within a day a block has width proportional to `Complexity`.

**Example**

Block `A` on chart corresponds to line 3 of the dataset. It takes 100% width of the day and has height of 3, for `Hours`.

Block `B` corresponds to line 4 and has width of 20%, corresponding to the `Complexity` of 2 and height of 7.

Trend line `C` is smoothed and built on day start / cumulative hours spent points.

Horizontal axis `D` is marked with calendar dates (skipping gaps)

Vertical axis `E` is measured in hours. The marks on the picture are for the bar heights for the example sake. Actual marks are just for incrementing number of hours.

Marks `F` are not represented on the chart and are there for reference, just like the dotted lines. Instead, blocks should be color coded depending on the `Complexity` value.

**Question**

I would like the chart to be drawn in the browser from JSON dataset. I can create a custom piece of code to do it but I'm wondering whether there is a library I could build this with. In my search attempts I couldn't find one doing exactly that. Specifically, variable block width seems to be something exotic. Please also offer your suggestions if you think there is a better way to represent a learning curve on chart.

Comment: _"I can create a custom piece of code to do it"_ Why have you not tried creating the code yourself?

Comment: Cause I'd rather spend time learning a new library than reinventing the wheel.

Comment: _"Cause I'd rather spend time learning a new library than reinventing the wheel."_ What is the difference? Each approach would consume equal amount of time. At least when reinventing wheel, you get the exact implementation to meet requirement, rather than having to possibly debug one or more developers' efforts. Debug your own work.

Comment: google charts can handle, using a stacked area series, set the bottom stack to transparent -- [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42510168/5090771) will you get you part of the way...

Comment: @WhiteHat Thanks, will give it a shot.