# google charts vAxis ticks multiple colors with respective light background

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, charts, google-visualization

This is my code of google chart vAxis ticks multiple colors

```
var gridlines = [
    '#ff0000',
    '#00ff00',
    '#0000ff'
];

var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(container);
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    var gridlineIndex = 0;
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(container.getElementsByTagName('rect'), function(rect, index) {
    if (rect.getAttribute('height') === '1') {
        rect.setAttribute('fill', gridlines[gridlineIndex]);
        gridlineIndex++;
    }
});

chart.draw(data, options);
```

Which results
[image]

But I want to be like [image]

How to do like the above, with different background colors under the ticks.
Please support me with this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39671447/5090771)...

Comment: Amazing, it helped me, Thank you @WhiteHat

Comment: Possible duplicate of [variable background colors in google line chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39669997/variable-background-colors-in-google-line-chart)

Answer (score 4):

[image: If you to do want to do like this]

I have done this using `stepped area` chart in the combo chart from the Google library...
where the values for each stepped area is the value for ticks.

Here is the link for [jsfiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/VikasRinvi/uwba6Ljy/1/)