# google charts curved line overlap

Tags: charts, google-visualization

With Google Charts I would like my curved line to overlap with a maximum or minimum value area.
Is it possible to combine the 'line'- and 'area'-chart types like this?

[curved line overlapping min/max areas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdVJ3.png)

I have put something in jsFiddle:

```
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});  
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Year', 'too low', 'value','too high'],
      ['2013',  500,      600,1200],
      ['2014',  500,      460,1200],
      ['2015',  500,     1400,1200],
      ['2016',  500,      300,1200],
      ['2017',  500,      540,1200]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Limited values',
      curveType: 'function',
      hAxis: {title: 'Year',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#FF'}},
      vAxis: {minValue: 0}
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

[jsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/mej58omb/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=mej58omb)

I don't want to use another library or chart engine.

Comment: something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39671447/5090771)?